# how do u make a program that checks many txt files

Tags: python

how do you make a program that checks many txt files to see if the input goes with any of the text in the files and prints where it was found.

Comment: what is `aline` ? what is `aline.split` ?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? What is `aline`?

Comment: @ furas and @ZeraRift sorry for not being clear

Comment: I Meant how do u make something read multiple txt files and you plug in the input and it checks the input and sees if it is in the txt files

Comment: We're not going to write a search function for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: read first file, see if input is in this file, read next file, see if input is in this file, etc. you can also use threads to check many files at the same time, and you can use queue to communicate between threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but I interpreted this as list the files in a given directory, and then check if the input is in the file.

```
import os
string = input("Please type the input ") 
directory = "c://files//python" 
for file in os.listdir(directory): 
    if file.endswith(".txt"): 
        filecontent = open(file, "r")
        if string in filecontent.read():
            print("The file that matches the input was found at" + file)
```

Line 2: Set the string to whatever the input is

Line 3: Use double slashes to avoid escape characters http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html

Line 4: Goes through every file in the directory. listdir returns a list with all the file names

Line 5: Can change this to .jpg, .png, etc

Line 6: Opens the file contents

Line 7: Reads the file's contents into a string, then check if the input is in said string